# How to upload an App to the App Store using Crorona

Tags: coronasdk

I have made a few games in Corona SDK and I would really like to publish them to the Apple App Store, please can i have help uploading them or at least converting them to an XCode project so I can get the Bundle ID to be able to upload it.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did not get you what you saying.there is no option to convert into x-Code.you have create bundle id in iTunes connect.then i corona project you have build.setting document.in that you have to mention that bundle id and do the build or refer this [link](http://fullycroisened.blogspot.in/2011/07/getting-your-bundle-id-correct-for-app.html).

For Bild:CTRL+R to build

If you did not get means explain your question clearly.